# place null values at last while sorting the data

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this data which i'm displaying in the table

```
[
    {
        "ID": 9,
        "Status": "Pending",
    },
    {
        "ID": 8,
        "Status": null,
    },
    {
        "ID": 7,
        "Status": "Pending",
    },
    {
        "ID": 10,
        "Status": null,
    },
    {
        "ID": 18,
        "Status": "Completed",
    },
    {
        "ID": 17,
        "Status": "In Progress",
    }
]
```

Sort Method:

> Ascending order :

```
 this.List.sort((a, b) => a[columnname] < b[columnname] ? 1 : a[columnname] > b[columnname]` ? -1 : 0);
```

> Descending order :

```
 this.List.sort((a, b) => a[columnname] > b[columnname] ? 1 : a[columnname] < b[columnname] ? -1 : 0);
```

and using sort function to sort the data in table issue is when i sort it, i want to place null values at the last. In current scenario they are in between other values

Like

```
Completed
null
In Progress
null
Pending 
null 
..
```

Comment: @cmgchess In both order i have button for ascending and descending order sort it is working fine for other places where null values is not there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly short way to do this would be:

```js
const tasks = [
  { "ID":  9, "Status": "Pending"     },
  { "ID":  8, "Status":  null         },
  { "ID":  7, "Status": "Pending"     },
  { "ID": 10, "Status":  null         },
  { "ID": 18, "Status": "Completed"   },
  { "ID": 17, "Status": "In Progress" },
];

const columnName = "Status";
tasks.sort(({ [columnName]: a }, { [columnName]: b }) => (
  (a == null) - (b == null) // move null values to the back of the array
  || -(a < b)               // move `a` to the front if it's smaller than `b`
  || +(a > b)               // move `a` to the back if it's greater than `b`
));

console.log(tasks);
```

In the snippet above we start with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/operators/destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) both comparator objects. `({ [columnName]: a }, { [columnName]: b })` stores the value of the `columnName` property of the first argument in the variable `a` and `b` for the second argument.

We then start with `(a == null) - (b == null)` to move the `null` values to the back of the array. This works because `true` coerces into `1` and `false` coerces into `0`. So if `a` is `null` and `b` is not, then `true - false` will evaluate to `1 - 0 //=> 1`. A positive return value means that `a` is placed behind `b`. If we are in the opposite scenario and `a` is not `null` but `b` is, then `false - true //=> -1`. A negative return value means that `a` is placed before `b`.

Both `1` or `-1` are truthy values, which cause the OR operator `||` to short circuit and return the first operand. If both values are `null` or both values are not `null`, then we end up with `true - true` or `false - false` which both evaluate to `0`. Since `0` is a falsy value, we'll move on to the second operand of the OR operator.

This brings us to `-(a < b)`, which checks if `a` is smaller than `b`. When this is true `-true` will evaluate into `-1`, so `a` is placed before `b`. If this is false then `-false` will evaluate into `-0`, which is a falsy value and moves us to the next operand in the OR chain. Assume that `a` and `b` are both `null`, then `null < null` is `false`, thus moving us on to the next OR operand. If `a` and `b` are both not `null`, say the status string, then the strings are compared based on code point values and `-1` is returned if `a` is smaller than `b`. Otherwise we move on to the final OR operand.

`+(a > b)` is very similar to `-(a < b)`, but returns `1` if `a` is greater than `b`. Placing `a` after `b` in the result.

Here are 6 example scenarios, showing the different outputs:

```
a = null, b = null
(a == null) - (b == null) || -(a < b) || +(a > b) /*
└─────────  0  ─────────┘    └─ -0 ─┘    └─  0 ─┘ */
//=>  0   a and b are equal

a = null, b = "a"
(a == null) - (b == null) || -(a < b) || +(a > b) /*
└─────────  1  ─────────┘                         */
//=>  1   a is placed after b

a = "a", b = null
(a == null) - (b == null) || -(a < b) || +(a > b) /*
└─────────  -1  ─────────┘                        */
//=> -1   a is placed before b

a = "a", b = "a"
(a == null) - (b == null) || -(a < b) || +(a > b) /*
└─────────  0  ─────────┘    └─ -0 ─┘    └─  0 ─┘ */
//=>  0    a and b are equal

a = "a", b = "b"
(a == null) - (b == null) || -(a < b) || +(a > b) /*
└─────────  0  ─────────┘    └─ -1 ─┘             */
//=> -1    a is placed before b

a = "b", b = "a"
(a == null) - (b == null) || -(a < b) || +(a > b) /*
└─────────  0  ─────────┘    └─ -0 ─┘    └─  1 ─┘ */
//=>  1    a is placed after b
```

A less cryptic version could be written like so:

```
tasks.sort(({ [columnName]: a }, { [columnName]: b }) => {
  if (a == null && b != null) return  1; // a after b
  if (a != null && b == null) return -1; // a before b
  if (a < b) return -1; // a before b
  if (a > b) return  1; // a after b
  return 0; // equal
});
```

---

To apply an `asc`/`desc` direction, but keep the `null` values at the back of the array, you can apply a modifier to the second part to inverse the sign (in case of a descending direction).

```
const modifiers = { asc: 1, desc: -1 };
const columnName = "Status";
const direction = "desc";

tasks.sort(({ [columnName]: a }, { [columnName]: b }) => (
  (a == null) - (b == null) // move null values to the back of the array
  || modifiers[direction] * (
    -(a < b)                // move `a` to the front if it's smaller than `b`
    || +(a > b)             // move `a` to the back if it's greater than `b`
  )
));

// without comments
tasks.sort(({ [columnName]: a }, { [columnName]: b }) => (
  (a == null) - (b == null) || modifiers[direction] * (-(a < b) || +(a > b))
));
```

Or:

```
tasks.sort(({ [columnName]: a }, { [columnName]: b }) => {
  if (a == null && b != null) return  1; // a after b
  if (a != null && b == null) return -1; // a before b
  if (a < b) return -1 * modifiers[direction]; // a before b
  if (a > b) return  1 * modifiers[direction]; // a after b
  return 0; // equal
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things for your sorting function

- You should not use `<` and `>` to compare strings. It does weird things with  upper/lower case, special characters, numbers, etc. there is a `String.localeCompare` function that can be used to compare strings
- If you want to sort `null` (or other special values) always at the end, just let it return a custom value that is always the same

This is a sample sorting function, that contains a check for number & string and always sorts null values together

```js
function mySort(data, columnName, reverse) {
    return data.sort((a, b) => {
        const valueA = reverse ? a[columnName] : b[columnName];
        const valueB = reverse ? b[columnName] : a[columnName];

        if (valueA === null) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (typeof valueA === 'string' && typeof valueB === 'string') {
            return valueA.localeCompare(valueB);
        }
        if (typeof valueA === 'number' && typeof valueB === 'number') {
            return valueA - valueB;
        }
    })
}
```

if you call `mySort(list, 'Status', false)` you will notice that all the null values are at the end while the rest is still properly sorted.

If you want to have `null` in the end for both descending and ascending you can adapt the special `=== null` check to something like

```js
if (valueA === null) {
   return reverse ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks i have checked in desc order null values are displayed first but i want to display null values at last in all cases

Comment: just adapt the value you are returning for your valueA === null check ;)